# render i value in a for loop, in flask

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I want to loop through the images stored in a serial number in my static/images folder.
My code is as below:

```
{% for x in range(5)%}
<img src="{{url_for('static', filename='images/{{i}}.jpg')}}" alt="Image">
{% endfor%}
```

but the html page is rendering it as :

```
<img src="/static/images/%7B%7Bi%7D%7D.jpg" alt="Image">
```

Any idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don’t need to use `{{ }}` again there. You already entered the [expression syntax](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#expressions) with the outer curly braces. So you just need to make sure that the expression is correct. You can do the following to concatenate the `i` with your path:

```
<img src="{{url_for('static', filename='images/' ~ i ~ '.jpg')}}" alt="Image">
```

This uses the [concatenation operator `~`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#other-operators) which first converts the operands into strings and then concats them.

Comment: Getting following :  TypeError: must be str, not int

Comment: @ganeshkonathala Sorry about that, edited my answer.